# How to make a scroll customization for mobile application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

Hi I am developing cross platform mobile application using cordova. In iOS platform my application scroll over when page is moved up and down. For that I have a code to stop scrolling and make my application like native application using the following script.

```
  $('body').on('touchstart','.scrollable',function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
      e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
    } else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight
              === e.currentTarget.scrollTop
                  + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) {
      e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
    }
  });
  $('body').on('touchmove','.scrollable',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

This works fine. My application do not scroll top and bottom. But in my code I am having `div` element with style attribute `overflow:auto;` this scrolls when the content exceed the div size but after using this code my div scroll is not working. How to make this work.
This is my css code for `div` element,

```
.tablediv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 136px;
    width: 414px;
    height: 375px;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

I need to scroll the elements that are necessary. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write JS for preventing overscroll, there is a setting in your config.xml for that:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```